# Cassandra SSTable and Memory mapped files

Tags: cassandra, memory-mapped-files, mappedbytebuffer

In this article [Reading and Writing from SSTable Perspective](https://dzone.com/articles/cassandra-11-reading-and)(yeah, quite old article) author says that indexdb and sstable files are warmed up using memory mapped files.

> Row keys for each SSTable are stored in separate file called index.db,
>   during start Cassandra “goes over those files”, in order to warm up. 
>   Cassandra uses memory mapped files, so there is hope, that when
>   reading files during startup, then first access on those files will be
>   served from memory.

I seee the usage of MappedByteBuffer in CommitLogSegment, but not for SSTable Loader/Reader. Also just mapping MappedByteBuffer to the file channel doesn't load the file into memory, I think load need to be called explicitly.

So my question is: when Cassandra starts up, how does it warm up? And am I missing something in this article's statement?

Answer (score 1):

'going over index files' most probably refers to index sampling. At some point Cassandra was reading the files on startup for the sampling purposes.

Since Cassandra 1.2 results of that process are now being persisted in [Partition summary](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutReads.html) file.